# Nginx is forwarding any subdomain to a specific port

Tags: nginx, docker, subdomain

I have my setup going for about 6 months and I just realized a pretty bad issue is happening. I'm sure it's something stupidly simple but I can't figure it out. Here is my setup:

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with Docker 19.03.12 and nginx 1.14.0. I have 6 containers running, all of which contain some sort of web app. In my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, I have 6 conf files (one for each of the webapps/containers), that only listen on 443 with SSL enabled. They each have a single location that look something like this:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.53:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
```

The "server_name" is a subdomain (e.g. my_sub1.mydomain.com, my_sub2.mydomain.com, etc.) and they each just go to the same IP on a different port. Not sure if matters but I'm using LetsEncrypt for my certs.

Everything has been working -- if I go to https://my_sub1.mydomain.com it gets routed to the correct webapp/container. However, if pick any random string as the subdomain (e.g. abc123.mydomain.com), it will redirect to the webapp that's running on 8080. My browser will give me a cert warning (naturally) but it does redirect to this webapp. I looked at all my configs in ../sites-enabled/ as well as in ../conf.d (which is empty) and I don't see where this subdomain is redirecting to...and why it's choosing this particular port (8080).

Is there some global setting I'm missing? Basically, I just want it to redirect on those subdomains that I've specified and 404 on everything else.

Comment: Where do you want this traffic to go?

Comment: Just die? Like if I type in jslkdfjsdfk.google.com, it just gives me a 404.

Comment: OK, put that in your default `server` block.

Comment: I added this and it didn't change any behavior:server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

Comment: Huh? Where is the `server_name`? And you don't have `default_server`?

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to your question.